# Swift - UITableViewCell? is not convertible to UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm new to Swift development and following many online tutorials. The majority of these Tutorials are referring to older versions on Xcode and the code is resulting in errors. Can anyone explain why the code below produces 'UITableViewCell?' is not convertible to UITableViewCella and how I go about fixing this problem.

I am using Xcode 7.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.item]
        return cell
}
```

Comment: Talking about "older versions" you should add to your question the version you're using.

Comment: Hi, i am using xcode 7 @vadian

Comment: is your "customcell" based on a custom UITableViewCell derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods

**1)**

```
func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell?
```

which returns an optional so you have to unwrap the optional

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("custom cell")!
```

---

The other method is preferable

**2)**

```
func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String,
                      forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

because it returns a non-optional

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("custom cell", forIndexPath:indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function returns UITableViewCell , while you are returning UITableViewCell?
check the type of cell
if its of type UITableViewCell? , you need to return cell!

( while cell is optional, the "!" unwrap it)